# How do you find out about deprecated features in a new release of Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Friends,

If I want to know about the new features of Oracle 11gR2 Database I can use the [New Features Guide.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10881/toc.htm)

Is there such a guide that lists functionality, features, parameters etc. that I should no longer be using because they have been superseded or deprecated?

If there isn't such a guide, which I suspect, what do you do to find out what has been deprecated in the next release of the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.2 - [Deprecated Features in Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/UPGRD/deprecated-features-oracle-database-12c-r2.htm#UPGRD-GUID-C34B4093-97BE-4237-9BE4-F45450F23BA3)

12.1 - [Deprecated and Desupported Features for Oracle Database 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60000)

11.2 - [Behavior Changes After Upgrading Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/changes.htm#UPGRD101)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct link or what you are after
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10819/changes.htm#UPGRD14999

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for the Response Rene - i gave the correct flag to Paul as he answered first.