# Features/Functionalities not supported in Oracle 12c when upgrading from 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c

I would like to know the functionalities affected when upgrading from 11g to 12c. For example, using WM_CONCAT in 11g works whereas its incompatible with 12c. What are the other functions / features of 11g not supported in 12c.

Comment: [You could look at the documentation...](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm). Worth noting that `wm_concat` was never documented or supported though, so that isn't a great example to pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ostensible question is a duplicate of [How do you find out about deprecated features in a new release of Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2628199/409172)

But the real issue is that `WM_CONCAT` was never an officially supported function.  It doesn't work in earlier versions in Express Edition or in any version where the Workspace Manager component was removed.  (This is partially Oracle's fault for waiting 30 years to include an official aggregate function, which forced people to look for alternates, but you still have to pay the price.)

The best solution is to replace `WM_CONCAT` with `LISTAGG`.  Some people create a custom function named `WM_CONCAT` but that's probably not a good idea anymore.  Oracle 12.2 introduced some nice new features to LISTAGG.  You'll want to migrate the code eventually, you might as well do it now.

Comment: Thanks for the help.